# Unable to click on any button after code has be written in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I implemented several buttons in my webpage as i am doing a booking system. I managed to restrict the user click on buttons in my webpage but my problem here is that user now cannot even select a button as when they try to click on the first button, my alert message will pop up asking them to only select one button. How do i allow users to select only one button and when they try to select another one, my alert message will come into usage. I suspect that is my count that is causing the problem.

here is my .cs code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (counter > 1)
    {
        Button1.Text = "Selected";
        Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
        Button2.Text = "Selected";
        Button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
        startingTime.Text = "9AM";
        endingTime.Text = "11AM";
    }

    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Please select one slot only');", true);
    }
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 1;
    if (counter > 0)
    {
        Button2.Text = "Selected";
        Button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
        Button3.Text = "Selected";
        Button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
        startingTime.Text = "10AM";
        endingTime.Text = "12PM";

    }

    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Please select one slot only');", true);
    }
}
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 1;
    if (counter > 0)
    {
        Button3.Text = "Selected";
        Button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
        startingTime.Text = "11AM";
        endingTime.Text = "1PM";

    }

    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Please select one slot only');", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a really specific reason you're not just using an option group?

Comment: No, there is no specific reasons. :-)

Comment: Well I think you would be a lot happier using that because that's what it was built for. You can even style them like buttons if I remember right (though that's off the top of my head right now). So if it works for you I'll move my comment to an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI - it's actually the RadioButtonList control - sorry for not being more specific at the time.

Answer (score 3):

This will always evaluate to `false`, so you always get into the `else` block:

```
int counter = 0;
if (counter > 1)
```

You should change `counter` **after** your code executed, also it should be a field of your class (otherwise any changes to it get lost as currently `counter` is gone once the method exits).

You could also use [`Button.Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled.aspx) to enable/disable buttons.

Comment: Sorry to ask but do you mean i should put a counter ++?

Comment: @kelly It depends on what you use the counter for. If `counter == 1` means the user can click only button 1, then a normal assignment would be better. Also, are you sure you want to compare `counter > 1` there? did you actually mean to compare `counter` for equality with 1 (`counter == 1`)?

Comment: I don't think comparing counter == 1 applies to my context as i have several buttons and usually I would not know which button the user will click. So if I only restrict to button1, users are allowed to click freely on button2 and button3 and so on.. Am i right?

Comment: @kelly Now i see what you are trying to do, just disable the other two buttons when the user clicks one of them. for example on Button1 click, you could set `Button2.Enabled = false` and `Button3.Enabled = false`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `int counter = 0` as global variable.

Answer (score 0):

you must try with this example for Button1

```
//Save your counter in Viewstate or InputHidden in order to persist

public int Counter 
{
    get
    {
        int s = (int)ViewState["Counter"];
        return (s == null) ? 0 : s;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Counter"] = value;
    }
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Counter = Counter + 1;

    if (Counter > 1)
    {
        Button1.Text = "Selected";
        Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
        Button2.Text = "Selected";
        Button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
        startingTime.Text = "9AM";
        endingTime.Text = "11AM";
    }

    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Please select one slot only');", true);
    }
}
```